# PHP SQLite3Result::fetchArray re-executes query

Tags: php, sqlite

I attached a function to the REGEXP keyword in PHP and I discovered that SQLite3Result::fetchArray re-executes the query! What inefficiency!

```
function _sqliteRegexp($pattern, $string)
{
    echo $pattern . ' - ' . $string . '<br/>';
    return preg_match('/' . $pattern . '/', $string);
}

$handle = new SQLite3($filename);
$handle->createFunction('regexp', '_sqliteRegexp', 2);

// (1)
$result = $handle->query("SELECT * FROM pages WHERE '" . $request_uri . "' REGEXP request LIMIT 1;");

// (2)
$result->fetchArray();
```

Giving, for example:

```
(1)
\/ - /admin/settings/1
\/sqlite - /admin/settings/1
\/admin - /admin/settings/1
\/admin\/logout - /admin/settings/1
\/admin\/settings(\/[0-9]+)? - /admin/settings/1

(2)
\/ - /admin/settings/1
\/sqlite - /admin/settings/1
\/admin - /admin/settings/1
\/admin\/logout - /admin/settings/1
\/admin\/settings(\/[0-9]+)? - /admin/settings/1
```

Both (1) and (2) echo the pattern and string the very same. I highly suspect the query is re-executed, which would be quite redundant. Is this a bug or just me being hastily concluding?

Comment: How many times is it called with `LIMIT 3`?

Comment: The LIMIT isn't influential. It merely makes the query stop earlier rather than going through the whole table. I've amended my post with what is echoed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A look into the [source code](http://git.php.net/?p=php-src.git;a=blob;f=ext/sqlite3/sqlite3.c;hb=HEAD) shows that `query` fetches the first row just to determine whether the result is empty, or not. The first call to `fetchArray` will execute the query again.
(So much for efficiency. Or side effects.)

If you are interested in no more than one row, use [`querySingle`](http://php.net/manual/en/sqlite3.querysingle.php) instead.

To answer your question: this works as designed. And that design is a bug.

Answer (score 0):

Check the methode "sqlite_regExp" on Havalite: http://www.havalite.com/?p=98

Works also with LIMIT:

```
if($rows = sqlite_regExp("SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE preg_match('/sql(lite)*/ui', myRow) LIMIT 1")){
    foreach($rows as $row) echo $row[0];
}
```

Comment: This is completely irrelevant. The problem is not attaching the regex functionality to SQL, but the fact that queries are executed twice. Which I discovered through using a custom regex function..