# PHP Sqlite fetchArray bug work around

Tags: php, sqlite

It seems fetchArray runs the query again, this makes it feel sluggish with complex SELECT queries.

- https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=64531
- [PHP SQLite3Result::fetchArray re-executes query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12981332/php-sqlite3resultfetcharray-re-executes-query)

Is there someway to have the database cache the 1st query it gets and just give the same results the second time?

Comment: If there were, it wouldn't have this bug.

Comment: It would be possible to change PHP's `sqlite3` module to do this caching. It would also be possible to replace PHP with some other language. Which one is easier for you is something you have to decide yourself.

Comment: If I were to use mysql would I have this issue?